# Is int assignable from char?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I note that

```
int number = 'a';
```

Is a sound  C#  statement

But that the expression

```
typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(char))
```

Returns false. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: 'a' will be converted by complier into int, so it's not.

Comment: `int` is not assignable from `char`. There is an implicit conversion when you assign it that way, which is completely different

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Isn't this a contradiction?

Nope. C# provides an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, but if you look at the documentation for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) it states for the return value:

> true if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c, or if c represents a value type and the current Type represents `Nullable<c>`. false if none of these conditions are true, or if c is null.

None of those conditions is true, so it returns `false`.

Comment: Also see [How to tell if Type A is implicitly convertible to Type B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224266/how-to-tell-if-type-a-is-implicitly-convertible-to-type-b)

Comment: Thanks. The method is much more complicated than the name suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The questions you are asking are slightly different.  The set of assignable **values** in C# are generally more permissive than the set of assignable **types** in the CLR.